# Sequence of functions $\sin^{n} (\pi x)$ cauchy in C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Equipping C[0,1] with its usual (supremum) norm, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $g_n(x)=\sin^{n} (\pi x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$. I'm trying to prove (or disprove) this sequence is cauchy.

Intuitively, I would think it is cauchy.

From the definition, I'm trying to show that for any $\epsilon >0$, sup$|\sin^{n} (\pi x)-\sin^{m} (\pi x)| < \epsilon$ whenever m,n>N.

I'm looking for a hint on how to go about showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $g_m$ is continuous with $g_m(0)=0$ and $g_m(\frac{1}{2})=1$  so let $x_m\in (0,\frac {1}{2})$ with $g_m(x_m)=\frac {1}{2}.$ We have $$\sup_{n>0}\|g_m-g_{m+n}\|\geq \sup_{n>0}|g_m(x_m)-g_{m+n}(x_m)|= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {1}{2}-g_{m+n}(x_m)=\frac {1}{2}.$$ So the Cauchy criterion is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

A "trick" I use is to bound the supremum of a function using it's derivative. You can look at $f_{nm}(x)=\sin ^n (\pi x) - \sin ^m (\pi x) $ and search for its maxima in $[0,1]$.

Edited: Another way is to recall (or prove) that a sequence of functions convergeces uniformally iff it is uniformally cauchy sequence (or that $C_\sup[0,1]$ is a Banach space).

Comment: Your second point doesn't seem right. First $\sin^n (\pi/2) =1$ for all $n$, so that convergence isn't even pointwise. I think this in fact proves the opposite of what OP wants, since the convergence is not uniform, then it cannot be Cauchy since the banach space of bounded continuous functions is complete under this norm.

Comment: @Yeldarbskich Yes you are correct, the convergence ofcourse cannot be uniform, and hence, it cannot be cauchy in $C_\infty[0,1]$ ("uniformally cauchy"). (I edited).